# Laravel - Removing model id from address bar while using RESTful controller

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Are there any helper functions that would not allow us to see the model's id in the address bar when viewing or editing details of a model?

E.g. if I try to edit the details of user with `id` 1, the address in the browser says: 
`myapp.dev/users/1/edit`

I'd rather it showed up as `myapp.dev/users/edit`

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: So how would the application know you're editing the user with id = 1, not with id = 2? And another question: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'll be routing using something like `Route::get('users/{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');`

Comment: I just don't want a user to be able to type in a query that would take them to some other user's page. Could I do this with middleware?

Comment: So is it to edit your own page?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, to allow the user to edit their own page only, and not someone else by inserting another number where their `id` is in the address bar

Comment: You don't need `id` in the url or the route at all then: just take the currently authenticated user details.

Comment: Yes, but I have other models in my app, I was giving an example of `User`

Comment: Well, it's not a good example then.

Comment: True. But is there any way ?

Comment: "So how would the application know you're editing the user with id = 1, not with id = 2?". If you don't pass it explicitly, where would it come from? And what is bad in seeing it in the url? Check the url of this very page - there is a question id there and there is no any problems with it.

Comment: you could hide the id in **hidden field** or use a **session**, but it's not foolproof anyway. both url and hidden field approach is not foolproof unless you do some checking on the server's end. @omrakhur i think you should read more on HTTP protocol and emphasize that HTTP is a **stateless** protocol. Basically, it stores no state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use POST then

```
<form action="{{ route('user.edit', $user->id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn ">Edit
</form>
```

You need to make some modification  in route

```
Route::post('users/{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is possible to make a "normal" route:

```
Route::get('users/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

and a method in your controller:

```
public function edit(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('users.edit',['user' => $user]);
}
```

When you have `$user` in your controller you can also find other models that belong to him using relationships. However, I also agree that it isn't the best idea. It's better to provide `id` of `user` in the path.

---

Actually, you will need logged-in user in each route like this. So your route should be using also `auth` middleware:

```
Route::get('users/edit', 'UserController@edit')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: I use `auth` middleware in the constructor of the controller

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you, to use [Laravel Hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids) and here are the [installation steps](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids#installation). After installation add service provider and do vendor publish

Simply encode the id before generating URL like

```
$encoded = Hashids::encode($id);
```

Then, your URL will be

http://mywebsite.com/users/e3423gsf562/edit

Here, the length and alphanumeric string in URL are configurable under config/hashids.php file

Then inside your controller, you could decode them and use it.

```
$id = collect(Hashids::decode($id))->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't thik that there is a helper function to do that.

If you just want to remove the id from the url, you can use HTML5 for that. There is this function that allows you to [change the URL without reloading the page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/):

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

**But maybe this is not what you want.** Maybe you just don't want user to change that id to access others users accounts. So you can use something called [Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization). This allows you to block users from doing something that they are not allowed to.